# Julia SimpleWebsockets Reconnect Logic

Tags: websocket, julia

I am using Julia's SimpleWebSockets to open a websocket connection.  I want it to reconnect after any disconnects.  Something is wrong with the `notify` commented below, it doesnt run after disconnect, thereby preventing the rest of the code from continuing.

```
using SimpleWebsockets

function connect_loop(C::Coinbase, msg_channel::Channel)
    while true
        client = WebsocketClient()

        ended = Condition()

        listen(client, :connect) do ws
            listen(ws, :message) do message
                put!(msg_channel, message)
            end
            listen(ws, :error) do reason
                @warn "Websocket connection error" reason...
                notify(ended)
            end
            listen(ws, :close) do reason
                @warn "Websocket connection closed" reason...
                notify(ended)
            end
            # for msg in C.command_channel
            #     send(ws, JSON.json(msg))
            # end
        end

        listen(C.client, :connectError) do err
            println("Websocket Connect Error.")
            notify(ended)  # This is not working !!!!!!!!!
        end

        println("connecting")
        @async open(C.client, "wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com")
        println("wait for ended")
        wait(ended)
        println("ended")
        sleep(2)
    end
end
```

Procedure is to connect on Wifi, then after successful connection disable the wifi and we should see it go into a reconnect loop, but instead it just stalls waiting on that `notify` call.

```
connecting
wait for ended
┌ Warning: Websocket connection closed
│   code = 1006
│   description = "could not ping the server."
└ @ Main ~/src/tibra/Tibra.jl/src/MarketDataIO/Coinbase.jl:60
ended
connecting
wait for ended
Websocket Connect Error.
```